# formatting printf statement in cpp file

Tags: c++, printf

I have a cpp file within an xcode application, but am having trouble formatting the printf correctly.

My code is:

```
b2Vec2 axisA = b2MulT(xfA.R, m_axis);
printf("axis A = XXX", axisA);
```

I need to know what to put in XXX to print out the value of the 'axisA' variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printf accepts only plain data types, so you need to break it down:

`printf("axis A = (%f,%f)", axisA.x, axisA.y);`

or

`printf("axis A = (%g,%g", axisA.x, axisA.y);`